# GEKKO - optimization in matrix form

Tags: constraints, gekko

I am trying to solve an optimization problem where I need to specify the problem and the constraints using a 2D matrix. I have been using SCIPY, where the 1D arrays are the requirements. I want to check if GEKKO allows one to specify the objective function, bounds and constraints using a 2D matrix.

I have provided details and a reproducible version of the problem in the post here:

[SCIPY - building constraints without listing each variable separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623986/scipy-building-constraints-without-listing-each-variable-separately)

Thanks
C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `m.Array` function in [gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I don't recommend that you use the `np.triu()` with the Gekko array because the eliminated variables will still solve but potentially be hidden from the results. Here is a solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
from gekko import GEKKO

p= np.array([4, 5, 6.65, 12]) #p = prices
pmx = np.triu(p - p[:, np.newaxis]) #pmx = price matrix, upper triangular

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
q = m.Array(m.Var,(4,4),lb=0,ub=10)
# only upper triangular can change
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if j<=i:
            q[i,j].upper=0 # set upper bound = 0

def profit(q):
    profit = np.sum(q.flatten() * pmx.flatten())
    return profit

for i in range(4):
    m.Equation(np.sum(q[i,:])<=10)
    m.Equation(np.sum(q[:,i])<=8)
m.Maximize(profit(q))

m.solve()

print(q)
```

This gives the solution:

```
[[[0.0] [2.5432017412] [3.7228765674] [3.7339217013]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [4.2771234426] [4.2660783187]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
```

Comment: Thanks again John. This is working, and I'll test it with the larger model (12X12) later today and confirm. I'm using this in a project paper, so will definitely cite GEKKO as advised on the GEKKO home page.